# Learn Bash or Powershell for Security Work?

Tags: powershell, bash-scripting

Is Bash more commonly used in security work than PowerShell? If so, why? (Now that Powershell can be used on Linux)

I tried to Google around for an answer on this, and the only questions we seem to have here are quite different, e.g.:

[What should I learn for Cyber security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119829/what-should-i-learn-for-cyber-security)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/is-powershell-ready-to-replace-my-cygwin-shell-on-windows

I know this is dangerously close to "opinion based", but this question has concrete answers in other areas - for example Kali over Windows / other Linux implementations for OS, Python over C#/Java in terms of the most common languages for security, etc.

Comment: Why is Powershell not popular on Linux? Because I snickered when you told me it was now available on Linux... Yeah, that's not going to catch on...

Comment: The answer is simple: you use the tool that does what you need. Learn the tool that you like better, if both are equal. All questions here of the type "which should I learn, X or Y?" are the same: make a utilitarian choice based on *your* context. We can't tell you what you *should* do because we don't know (and can't know) all of your context.

Comment: My answer to these questions is always the same, and basically the same as what schroeder said: it doesn't really matter where you start your infosec journey; if you pick a technology (_any_ technology) and learn it deeply enough to understand its security, then you're well on your way to being a security professional. _Are there linux shops that need bash security experts?_ Yes. _Are there Windows shops that need PS security experts?_ Yes. _Are there **more** linux shops than Windows shops?_ Does it matter? Are you planning to work for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Bash more commonly used in security work than PowerShell?

Yes.  For example, github appears to have more Security sh/bash scripts than it has ps1 scripts:

| Search Term | Hits |
| --- | --- |
| [github security sh](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20security%20sh) | 14,100,000 |
| [github security bash](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20security%20bash) | 9,110,000 |
| [github security ps1](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20security%20ps1) | 635,000 |

> If so, why? (Now that Powershell can be used on Linux)

Rome wasn't built in a day.  People have been writing sh and sh-compatible scripts on Unix and Linux for 40 years.  Powershell may now be available on Linux, but it will still take quite some time for adoption to spread.